# Retrieve/Loop through Custom App.config Settings

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

I am trying to take the custom configuration section from my app.config file and pass the values to a query for updating etc.

Here is the code for my CustomConfig assembly

```
using System;

using System.Configuration;

namespace CustomConfig
{
public class Element : ConfigurationElement
{
    private const string LevelKey = "level";
    private const string DaysAgedValue = "daysaged";

    [ConfigurationProperty(LevelKey, IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
    public string Level
    {
        get { return (string)this[LevelKey]; }
        set { this[LevelKey] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty(DaysAgedValue, IsRequired = true, IsKey = false)]
    public string DaysAged
    {
        get { return (string)this[DaysAgedValue]; }
        set { this[DaysAgedValue] = value; }
    }

}

public class ElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public ElementCollection()
    {
        this.AddElementName = "Settings";
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return (element as Element).Level;
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new Element();
    }

    public new Element this[string key]
    {
        get { return base.BaseGet(key) as Element; }
    }

    public Element this[int ind]
    {
        get { return base.BaseGet(ind) as Element; }
    }
}

public class Section : ConfigurationSection
{
    public const string sectionName = "PrintLogPurgeSettings";

    [ConfigurationProperty("", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    public ElementCollection PrintLogPurgeSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return this[""] as ElementCollection;
        }
    }

    public static Section GetSection()
    {
        return (Section)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(sectionName);
    }
}
}
```

Here is my app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <!--<section name="PrintLogPurgeSettings" type="CustomConfig.PrintLogPurgeConfigSection, PrintingServiceLogPurge" />-->
    <section name="PrintLogPurgeSettings" type="CustomConfig.Section, PrintingServiceLogPurge" />
</configSections>

<!---Print Log Level and Age Settings-->
<PrintLogPurgeSettings>
    <Settings level="1" daysaged="30"/>
    <Settings level="2" daysaged="60"/>
    <Settings level="3" daysaged="60"/>
    <Settings level="4" daysaged="90"/>
    <Settings level="5" daysaged="90"/>
    <Settings level="6" daysaged="180"/>
</PrintLogPurgeSettings>
```

I would like to loop through the items in PrintLogPurgeSettings (1-6) and send them to a query for processing.

Comment: Why don't you use ConfigurationManager?

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
CustomConfig.Section c = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("PrintLogPurgeSettings") as CustomConfig.Section;
foreach (CustomConfig.Element element in c.PrintLogPurgeSettings.Cast<CustomConfig.Element>())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", element.Level, element.DaysAged);
}
```

It prints:

```
1:30
2:60
3:60
4:90
5:90
6:180
```